# Can't read global variables in a javascript function :(

Tags: javascript, scope

I am having a strange problem with global variables disappearing on me. Here is some stripped down semi-pseudo-code:

```
var globy = 99;

jQuery.get("file", function(){
  check();
})

function check(){
 main();
}

function main(){
 forloop
  whileloop
   forloop
    while(test()){}
}

function test(){
  //globy causes a reference error here
}
```

That should explain the code structure. All the way up to the test() function "globy" is fine but suddenly inside test() all global variables disappear. What the heck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are wrapping everything in a `$(document).ready()` but have your `test()` function outside of the document ready you will have a scoping issue.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var globy = 99;

    jQuery.get("file", function () {
        check();
    })

    function check() {
        main();
    }

    function main() {
        forloop
        whileloop
        forloop
        while (test()) {}
    }
});

function test() {
    //globy causes a reference error here
}
```

Besides that it will be hard to say without the real js.

Comment: Aha. You are right! I had test() actually in a separate file that I was including in at the top. I guess for now I can leave the document ready part out. Would getScript() allow me to pull the external script inside the `$(document).ready()`?

Answer (score 1):

Your test() function is probably defined outside the scope where `globy` resides. Without more detail, it's hard to say.

Comment: A way to circumvent this is to use `window.globy`. If you *must* use globals, that is.